# Eigen: Acessing scattered element in a matrix

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen, masking, eigen3

In MATLAB I am able to select a scattered submatrix e.g.:

```
A = [1 ,2 ,3;4,5,6;7,8,9]
A([1,3],[1,3]) = [1,3;7,9]
```

Is there a clever way to do this with Eigen?

Answer (score 3):

Not in a generic manner, but if your access pattern is regular, you can use an Eigen::Map with appropriate strides:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Eigen::Matrix3d A;

  A << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;

  std::cout << Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix2d, 0, Eigen::Stride<6, 2> >(A.data());
  return 0;
}
```

See
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Stride.html